# grafana: export data from the dashboard

Tags: curl, export, grafana

I have a Grafana dashboard that looks like a table with some data.
How can I get values from this dashboard table?

I tried making the following request:
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer My_Token" 'https://grafana.blablabla.com/api/dashboards/uid/UID00001/?viewPanel=2&orgId=1'
However, I got something similar to json+html, but it doesn't contain any data from the dashboard table. It seems to be dashboard markup without data.

Can you please advise me on how to request data specifically from the table?

I have tried a query like this:
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer My_Token" 'https://grafana.blablabla.com/api/dashboards/uid/UID00001/?viewPanel=2&orgId=1' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
But the answer also does not contain data from the table.